# NUnit Configuration and Inheritence of Parameterized TestFixture in Subclasses

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, automated-tests

I'm building a Selenium suite.  I am trying to figure out how to best run a TestFixture for all browsers and all our clients.  Here is what I tried to do, which doesn't work due for "not having a suitable constructor"

Here is my base class to give a browser and method to create a webdriver to the sub classes.

```
[TestFixture(Browser.Chrome)]
[TestFixture(Browser.Firefox)]
[TestFixture(Browser.IE)]
[TestFixture(Browser.Safari)]
abstract class WebDriverTest
{
    protected IWebDriver driver;
    protected Browser browser;

    public WebDriverTest(Browser browser)
    {
        this.browser = browser;
    }

    protected IWebDriver CreateWebDriver()
    {
        CreateWebDriver(browser);
    }
}
```

And a TestFixture for all clients. I would have other similar tests classes for features belonging to certain sets of clients.

```
[TestFixture(Client.Client1)]
[TestFixture(Client.Client2)]
abstract class AllClientsTest : WebDriverTest
{
    protected Client client;

    public AllClientsTest(Browser browser, Client client) : base(browser)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    protected Navigator GetNavigator()
    {
        return NewNavigator(client)
    }
}
```

And finally the class where I would write a test with the webdriver that runs for all clients.

```
class InheritanceTest : AllClientsTest
{
    public InheritanceTest(Browser browser, Client client) : base(browser, client)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(browser + ":" + client);
    }
}
```

Is something like this even possible?  I'm trying to keep configuration independent of TestRunner and not repeat myself in making lot's of parameters in test cases (which can be data driven initialized). I also tried adding an attribute like `[TestFixture(typeof(Browser), typeof(Client))]` in the `AllClientsTest` class.

If there was a data driven way to set up the `[TestFixture]` attribute, I could load both sets of config in the base class and load the config there and eliminate the need of the superclasses, which are basically solely being used to conveniently run a bunch of tests.

Comment: `AllClientsTest` expects two parameters in it's constructor, `Browser` & `Client`, you are only giving it a `Client`. You are not passing in anything to `InheritanceTest`. However, I would say the test itself should be liable to what browser to run. `InheritanceTest` passes a `Client` and a `Browser` down all the way to `WebDriverTest`.

Comment: The idea is I would like the TestFixture that runs test to have a browser and client ready to use in SetUp/TestFixtureSetUp method (depending on where the specific test fixture needs a new WebDriver/Navigator).  If I pass these in the test method I can't take advantage of common setup code between tests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the SetUpFixture feature of NUnit? I've done something vaguely similar to what you're trying via that.

I wrote [a blogpost on using SetUpFixture for warming up sites](http://frazzleddad.blogspot.com/2010/03/warming-up-sites-before-running.html), which was a different task, though. It may be helpful.